# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS How to check what CVEs were patched after an update

Tags: package-management, updates, security

So I read about Krack Attack and noticed that Ubuntu released a patch to fix the issues (https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3455-1/).

I updated via

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and checked with the Software Updater.

How do I verify that my system has installed the packages listed in the security notice above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it with `apt-get changelog pkgnmae`, for example:

```
apt-get changelog wpasupplicant
```

and you should get something like this as output

> wpa (2.1-0ubuntu1.5) trusty-security; urgency=medium
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: Multiple issues in WPA protocol
>
>   - debian/patches/2017-1/*.patch: Add patches from Debian jessie
>   - CVE-2017-13077, CVE-2017-13078, CVE-2017-13079, CVE-2017-13080,
>       CVE-2017-13081, CVE-2017-13082, CVE-2017-13086, CVE-2017-13087,
>       CVE-2017-13088   * SECURITY UPDATE: Denial of service issues
>   - debian/patches/2016-1/*.patch: Add patches from Debian jessie
>   - CVE-2016-4476
>   - CVE-2016-4477
>
>   -- Marc Deslauriers   Mon, 16 Oct 2017
>     08:20:18 -0400

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal type the following command:
`apt list --installed`
 and verify if the correct packages are listed.